# How to replace normal date to unix date in the csv file using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, unix, csv

Im having 30-03-2015 date field in my mysql db.Im fetching the date as it is in the db in the csv file,but how to get the in the unix format during  fetching from the database

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');



$servername = "localhost";
$username = "testuser";
$password = "";
$dbname = "stats";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "welcome";
$list = array ('date', 'success', 'failure','count');

 $sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('date')from h_statistics;";
      $users_profile_user_id = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 


      $fp = fopen("user_profile19.csv", "w");
        fputcsv($fp, $list);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users_profile_user_id, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      fputcsv($fp, $row);

    }

    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert this date format to "normal" mysql format, do this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%m-%Y') from h_statistics // 2015-03-30
```

where `'%d-%m-%Y'` describes what format you have used in your string representation of the date. Also remember to drop those single quotes from `date` as you don't want to evaluate 'date' string, but the value in `date` field.

To get the timestamp:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%m-%Y')) from h_statistics // 1427666400
```

Answer (score 1):

for unix timestamp you use your query like this

```
$sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('date','%d-%m-%Y')) from h_statistics";
```

Comment: @Abhik sir thank you  for your important information.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in query like.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) FROM visits
```

Here is another list of date time functions.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

so your date form is like this `30-03-2015` so use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to format the date and then change it to `unix timestamp` .

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y')) from h_statistics;
```